# How can I set up an NSWindowDelegate to detect windowDidEnterFullScreen and similar events?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I figured out that there is an [`windowDidEnterFullScreen`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowdelegate/1419116-windowdidenterfullscreen?changes=l_8) function in `NSWindowDelegate` to detect when the window enters fullscreen.

I have:

```
class WindowDelegate: NSWindowDelegate {
    func windowDidEnterFullScreen(_ _: Notification) {
        // Called when window will enter fullscreen
    }
}
```

How can I get the application to register this so the function will be called when the window enters fullscreen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A storyboard application has a window in `Window Controller` in `Main.storyboard`. By default, `Window Controller` uses the `NSWindowController` class. First you need to add `NSWindowController` to your class, and I suggest renaming to `WindowController`:

```
class WindowController: NSWindowController, NSWindowDelegate
```

Next, find `Window Controller` in `Window Controller Scene` in `Main.storyboard` and select it, then Custom Class in the Inspector, type your custom class name (`WindowController`) into the class field. This will tell the application to use your custom window controller/delegate instead of the default `NSWindowController`.

[image: Inspector Custom Class]

Comment: FYI: While using your own `NSWindowController` subclass is generally useful, it's not strictly necessary in this case. The callback OP is interested in (`windowDidEnterFullScreen`) is available on `NSWindowDelegate`. You could add a new object of your `NSWindowDelegate`-conforming class to your storyboard, and link that directly to your windows (they can even be actual `NSWindow`s, no need to subclass), and it should work.

Comment: You don't even need a custom delegate in this case, just observe the notification.

Comment: @Willeke But which way is cleaner?

Comment: It depends on what you need and it's a matter of taste.